# Unity finding Transform object in scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new at game dev, and I have question, I have my enemies prefabs, and enemy script, contains

```
public Transform player;
```

So Instead of every time putting my player into that 'slot', I want to make, script will be finding my player, I tried

```
private Transform player = GameObject.Find("player")
```

but it shows error
Here is the full script

```
public class Enemies : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player = GameObject.Find("Player");
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 movement;
    public float speed = 5f;
    public int health;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 direction = player.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        rb.rotation = angle;
        direction.Normalize();
        movement = direction;

    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move(movement);
    }
    void Move(Vector2 direction)
    {
        rb.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (direction * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        health = health - 1;
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can't use `Find` in a static context. (Which is probably the error you are referring to.)

It goes a bit deeper into how c# works but in simple words: The class fields are all initialized even before the constructor is executed and thus at a moment when there still is no instance.

Secondly: [`GameObject.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) returns a `GameObject` not a `Transform`.

So if anything it would probably rather be

```
// Best would still be to drag this in if possible
[SerializeField] private Transform player;

void Start()
{
    if(!player) player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

In general I always recommend to not use `Find` at all if anyhow possible. It is basically just a more expensive way of using some static or manager/provider based code